# ImageView onClick runs only one time

Tags: android

I'm developing simple webview app and thought of adding some image that works as a button when you click it, it opens share intent.

My app consists of login page activity. After login, it redirects you to webview.

webview.java
This code inside OnCreate

```
ImageView ShareButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ShareButton);
        ShareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                try {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "URL" );
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
                    startActivity(shareIntent);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ShareButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_img" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

At first install and first run of the webview activity the onclick method works but if i close the app and reopen it again, onclick not working anymore and i have to clear data/cache or reinstall.

What's happening here?

I tried to create separate method outside OnCreate then call it inside OnCreate but it's not working also.

I also tried to set android:onClick="Click" inside image in xml file of webview but errors shows that i should create Click method in login.java instead of webview.java. I created the method there and implemented the code inside a listener but it's not working also.

logs:

```
I/FIAM.Display: Unbinding from activity: webv
I/FIAM.Headless: Removing display event component
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 43402
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 414574
D/FA: Connected to remote service
D/FA: Application going to the background
...
I/FIAM.Headless: went foreground
I/FIAM.Display: Binding to activity: webv
I/FIAM.Headless: Setting display event component
I/FIAM.Headless: Forcing fetch from service rather than cache. Test Device: false | App Fresh Install: true
...
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 534253
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
I/FIAM.Headless: Fetching campaigns from service.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite not found.
D/FA: Connected to remote service
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module 
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
...
V/NativeCrypto: Read error: ssl=0x756fb141a098: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
V/NativeCrypto: Write error: ssl=0x756fb141a098: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
D/TrafficStats: tagSocket(201) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
V/NativeCrypto: SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x756fb141a098: I/O error during system call, Success
...
```

Comment: Is it going into exception block ? please add logs if its going in to exception block.

Comment: I updated the question with debug log.

Comment: these logs for first install(fresh) but when i force close app then debug again, no errors show.

Answer (score 0):

**I try this code in onCreate and its work fine**

```
 ImageView ShareButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ShareButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            try {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "URL" );
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                Intent shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null);
                startActivity(shareIntent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Button clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you try to force turn off the app then reopen and try, it's still not working for me,